# Quadratic equation. Nested class

Tags: java

Good afternoon. I wrote a program to solve a quadratic equation. The problem is that it is not accepted because the nested class has the static modifier. Please correct: Calculation of discriminant should be done by nested class. Please tell me how this can be implemented.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 
public class Abc{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a: ");
        double a = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter b: ");
        double b = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter c: ");
        double c = scanner.nextDouble();
        double massiv[] = Disko.calc(a, b, c);
        System.out.println("Number of decisions = " + massiv.length);
        for (double x : massiv) {
            System.out.println("x = " + x);
        }
    }
 
     class Disko{
        public static double[] calc(double a, double b, double c) {
            double d = b * b - 4 * a * c;
            if (a == 0) {
                System.out.println("degenerate x");
                System.exit(1);
            } else if (d > 0) {
                return new double[]{(-b - Math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a), (-b + Math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)};
            } else if (d == 0) {
                return new double[]{-b / (2 * a)};
            } else {
                return new double[]{};
            }
            return new double[]{};
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "The problem is that it is not accepted because the nested class has the static modifier" - it doesn't in the code you've posted. What's "not accepting" it? Please provide more context.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, The teacher gave the task to develop a program for calculating the square root of the equation. I provided this code. After checking, the code was returned to me for revision, citing the fact that the discriminant should be calculated by a nested class. And at the moment the nested class has the static modifier.

The task itself looks like this:
Develop a class for square solutions. The discrimination calculation must check the nested class. After compilation, explain the structure of the class files. Consider using a nested class.

Comment: "And at the moment the nested class has the static modifier" - again, no it doesn't in the code you've shown us. You've declared `class Disko` - where is the static modifier in that class declaration? (Personally I see absolutely no benefit in using a nested class for this and think it's a bizarre requirement, but there we go...)

Comment: @JonSkeet. Maybe she means the line after the `class Disko` - this one `public static double[] calc(double a, double b, double c)`. Or, in general, that the program should be implemented in a different way?

Comment: That's a method though, not a nested class. It sounds like you really need to talk with your teacher about this.

Comment: @JonSkeet. Thanks a lot for your help and your time. Your opinion is very important to me. I'll talk to the teacher! :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing your nested class to something like

```
class QuadraticEquation {

   double a,b,c;
   
   public QuadraticEquation(double a, double b, double c) {
       this.a = a;
       this.b = b;
       this.c = c;
    }

    public double[] calc() {
         // Add your solution here...   
    }
}
```

Then your main class would create an instance of the QuadraticEquation and then call calc() to get the result.

```
// get your a,b,c values as you have
QuadraticEquation eq = new QuadraticEquation(a, b, c);
double[] result = eq.calc();
// ...
```

The difference in approach is subtle and has to do with the knowledge that the nested class encapsulates about what it represents and what behavior it has. With interfaces it can be made generic. Other classes can extend it. Methods can be added to enrich its behavior.  A call to a static method does not have the same power.